# How do query among many collections then write result to corresponding collection

Tags: mongodb

If I want to query users' age > 18,

and export result to corresponding collection,

How could I do it by rewriteing the following script?

The following is psuedo code

```
source_collections = ["user_1", "user_2", ..., "user_999"]
output_collections = ["result_1", "result_2", ..., "result_999"]
pipeline = [
    {
        "$match":{"age": > 18}
    }
    { "$out" : output_collections }
]
cur = db[source_collections].runCommand('aggregate',
    {pipeline: pipeline,allowDiskUse: true})
```

Answer (score 1):

The script you're looking for is something like:

```
var prefix_source = 'user_';
var prefix_output = 'result_';
var source_collections = [];
var output_collections = [];
var numCollections = 999;

for (var i = 1; i <= numCollections; i++) {
    source_collections.push(prefix_source + i);
    output_collections.push(prefix_output + i);
}

var pipeline = [{'$match': {age: {'$gt': 18}}}, {'$out': ''}];  for (var currentCollection = 0; currentCollection < source_collections.length; currentCollection++) {
    pipeline[pipeline.length - 1]['$out'] = output_collections[currentCollection];
    var cur = db[source_collections[currentCollection]].runCommand('aggregate', {pipeline: pipeline,allowDiskUse: true});
}
```

And while you're at it, the `var cur = ...` line could be simplified to

```
db[source_collections[currentCollection]].aggregate(pipeline, {allowDiskUse: true});
```

*Note*: I've added a piece that generates your arrays for you, as I'm sure you're not looking to write them by hand :D